Пути к файлам передаются программе в качестве аргументов!
Одно из заданий это то? что надо сделать, что пути к файлам передаются программе в качестве аргументов!
я знаю что оно делатеся вот так:
//string circleFilePath = args[0];
//string dotsFilePath  = args[1];

И когда мы запускаем проект должно быть что-то вроде такого:
dotnet run <path-to-input-file>
dotnet run <path-to-input-file> <path-to-input-file>

а у меня оно пока что делается вот так:
в самом Main:
string circleFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Oberg\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PortFolio\\2024\\ПерфомансЛаб\\Perfomance-Lab\\Perfomance-Lab2\\File1.json";

string dotsFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Oberg\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PortFolio\\2024\\ПерфомансЛаб\\Perfomance-Lab\\Perfomance-Lab2\\File2.json";

И я не понимаю как сделать... То есть сам проект можно как-то скомпилировать и это уже будет отдельно файл. который запускается не с помощи Visual Studio, а с помощью командной строки? и если эти файлы которые надо подгрузить находятся в той же папке где и сам скомпилированный проектик то мы просто пишем... dotnet run <path-to-input-file>.
Я просто никогда еще ничего не "компилировал" и даже не знаю что это такое...
using System.Text.Json;
namespace Perfomance_Lab2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            

            try
            {
                string circleFileJson = File.ReadAllText(circleFilePath);
                Circle circle = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Circle>(circleFileJson);

                string dotsFilePathJson = File.ReadAllText(dotsFilePath);
                Dictionary<string, Dot> dotsDictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dot>>(dotsFilePathJson);
                List<Dot> dots = new List<Dot>(dotsDictionary.Values);

                foreach (var dot in dots)
                {
                    double distance = Calculate(circle, dot);
                    PrintResult(circle, distance);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error reading the data from json: \n{ex.Message}");
            }

        }

        static double Calculate(Circle circle, Dot dot)
        {
            double circleX = circle.Dot.X;
            double circleY = circle.Dot.Y;

            double dotX = dot.X;
            double dotY = dot.Y;

            return (double)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dotX - circleX, 2) + Math.Pow(dotY - circleY, 2));

        }

        static void PrintResult(Circle circle, double distance)
        {
            if(distance < circle.Radius)
                Console.WriteLine("The dot is located indise of the circle");
            else if(distance > circle.Radius)
                Console.WriteLine("The dot is located outside of the circle");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The dot is located on the radius of the circle");
        }
    }
}


Зачем вам dotnet если можно (и нужно) писать сразу путь_до_вашего_exe агрумент1 аргумент2 аргумент3 ....?

Ничего не понял) . Можешь просяснить пожалуйста а то мне завтра это уже сдавать придется

Ну так советую открыть документацию, хотяб базовые  уроки, и посмотреть что вы делаете... Вот как я вам должен тут что-то объяснить? Вы когда запускаете, к примеру, браузер, вы пишете в консоли что-то run что-то? Думаю нет, ибо вы просто тыкаете 2 раза и открываете нужное приложение. Почему вы не делаете тоже самое со своим приложением? Соберите его в .exe файл и запускайте его напрямую, без всяких консольных команд. Ну а если вам принципиально нужны консольные команды, то открываете документацию и смотрите как передаются аргументы, увидите там dotnet run ... -- аргументы.

Вы написали столько слов...  вместо этого уже бы давно объяснили... Спасибо вам большое...

А я выше не объяснил? Извините, но я не знаю, как еще короче объяснить это... Так что, может вместо претензий, перечитаете выше сказанное, а также дополнительно посмотрите документацию, чтоб уж точно понять то, как решить вашу задачу?

я понял, ты просто себе рейтинг накручиваешь комментариями или еще что то ... Только зря на вас время потратил

Советую изучить ресурс, на котором вы находитесь, перед тем как обвинять человека в чем либо. На SO комментарии не дают ничего, ни рейтинга (даже если его лайкнут), ни каких либо баллов, ничего! На SO ценится вклад (ответы и вопросы), которые должны быть четко сформулированы и решать одну конкретную задачу. И вот с эти у вас проблемы, ибо вы спрашиваете про "запуск приложения с аргументами", я вам прямым текстом сказал как это делать, а тут внезапно появляется некая IDE и ее настройки, о которой ни слова в вопросе не было. А теперь подумайте, кто "дурак". Минус вам от меня за это.

получилось у меня разобраться и сделать. а сам путь файлам надо
указать в:
Project → task4 Properties → Debug General → Open debug launch profile UI → in Command Line Arguments
и туда вставляем ссылку на файлы.

using System.Text.Json;

namespace task2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // это для себя
            // string circleFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Oberg\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PortFolio\\2024\\ПерфомансЛаб\\Perfomance-Lab\\Perfomance-Lab2\\File1.json";
            // string dotsFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Oberg\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PortFolio\\2024\\ПерфомансЛаб\\Perfomance-Lab\\Perfomance-Lab2\\File2.json";

            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: dotnet run <circleFilePath> <dotsFilePath>");
                return;
            }

            // путь к файлу закинул в Project - task4 Properties - Debug General - Open debug launch profile UI - in Command Line Arguments два пути там:
            // string circleFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Oberg\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PortFolio\\2024\\ПерфомансЛаб\\Perfomance-Lab\\Perfomance-Lab2\\File1.json";
            // string dotsFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Oberg\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PortFolio\\2024\\ПерфомансЛаб\\Perfomance-Lab\\Perfomance-Lab2\\File2.json";

            string circleFilePath = args[0];
            string dotsFilePath = args[1];
            try
            {
                string circleFileJson = File.ReadAllText(circleFilePath);
                Circle circle = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Circle>(circleFileJson);

                string dotsFilePathJson = File.ReadAllText(dotsFilePath);
                Dictionary<string, Dot> dotsDictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dot>>(dotsFilePathJson);
                List<Dot> dots = new List<Dot>(dotsDictionary.Values);

                foreach (var dot in dots)
                {
                    double distance = Calculate(circle, dot);
                    PrintResult(circle, distance);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error reading the data from json: \n{ex.Message}");
            }

        }

        static double Calculate(Circle circle, Dot dot)
        {
            double circleX = circle.Dot.X;
            double circleY = circle.Dot.Y;

            double dotX = dot.X;
            double dotY = dot.Y;

            return (double)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dotX - circleX, 2) + Math.Pow(dotY - circleY, 2));

        }

        static void PrintResult(Circle circle, double distance)
        {
            if (distance < circle.Radius)
                Console.WriteLine("The dot is located indise of the circle");
            else if (distance > circle.Radius)
                Console.WriteLine("The dot is located outside of the circle");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The dot is located on the radius of the circle");
        }
    }
}

